# Is recording audio allowed in XAML Browser Applications

Tags: c#, audio, xbap, audio-recording

I am searching ways to perform audio recording from the client's computer. I have stumbled upon [XAML Browser Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAML_Browser_Applications) - XBAPs, and I want to make sure, is it possible to perform audio recording using it?

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to run the XAML Browser Application in partial trust, then the answer is No.

To record audio using .Net, the only current method is to use Interop methods, to use the Windows API's for WaveIn or similar technology based on the version of windows the application is running on.

This link explains the [Windows Presentation Foundation Security Sandbox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480229.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480229.aspx) - Relevant quote;

> Interop Methods/properties that exist
>   to enable interop to unmanaged code
>   are not enabled in partial-trust (for
>   example WindowInteropHelper). The
>   rationale here is that using these
>   classes is not a scenario for partial
>   trust.